# How to import or convert a sql script into Grails domain classes

Tags: grails

I have a database schema exported to a sql script. I wonder if there is a Grails command to create automatically the domain clases (.groovy) getting all the data from the sql script.

This is an extract of the script database.sql:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alojamiento`.`Usuario` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `nombre_usuario` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `alojamiento`.`Localidad`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alojamiento`.`Localidad` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
(...)
```

Comment: you could try http://grails.org/GRAG, but it reads existing tables, not a script.

Comment: It looks exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try with this tool, and I will come back :)

Comment: Don't use GRAG - it's abandoned and way out of date. Use http://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [db-reverse-engineer plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) to generate domain classes from your database.

Comment: Yep, it works perfectly. The tutorial is quite easy to follow (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/single.html#4%20Tutorial)
Just to simplify even more, in Config.groovy, I only wrote the next to copy all the tables:
grails.plugin.reveng.packageName = 'name_of_the_package.subpackage'